# TFS - Java SDK : How to create a child relation link type on Workitems

Tags: java, tfs, tfs-workitem, workitem

I am currently making my way through the examples given by Microsoft in the
TFS 2012 SDK for Java.
Through the example **AddRelatedLinkToWorkItem** in the snippets I am able to create a link between two workitems.
This is always a RelatedLink.
But I could not find out how to create a Child <-> Parent-Relationship between two WorkItems.
I found

```
newRelatedLink(WorkItem sourceWorkItem, WorkItem targetWorkItem, int linkTypeId, java.lang.String comment, boolean readOnly)
```

in the LinkFactory-Class.
I assume with the third parameter: **linkTypeId**
I am able to change the link to a child-parent-ralation.
But I could not find any information about linkTypeId.

Any help would be appreciated...

Jogi

Comment: Did you mean workitem linktype. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemstore(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: Hi, it looks like the hierarchy, namings etc are different between C# and Java.
I am looking how to make this link 
https://github.com/jogi-k/team-explorer-everywhere/blob/master/source/com.microsoft.tfs.sdk.samples.snippets/src/com/microsoft/tfs/sdk/samples/snippets/AddRelatedLinkToWorkItem.java#L41 
to a Child-Parent-Link.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the linkTypeID I get from .NET TFS API. It should the same with Java SDK. You can try with it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!
This pragmatic solution is working, I can use "2" in the sample to create the wanted parent-child relationship.
I hope I find some time over the weekend to form a programmatic solution, based on this discussion-entry I found, which describes the reverse way:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/954ca23d-843d-49e3-b83f-9ebfd5e9832d/tfs-java-sdk-all-links-have-the-related-workitem-type?forum=tee